# Convention in electrochemical cell notation

Tags: electrochemistry, notation

While writing the cell notation for a cell, doesn't one have to write the two states in which a species exists in a sequence appropriate to the reaction in which they participate?

For example, in the Daniell cell reaction, shouldn't it always be written $\ce{Zn}|\ce{Zn^2+}$, and never, $\ce{Zn^2+}|\ce{Zn}$?

I didn't see anything in the definitions, and I saw a question asking for the cell reactions for this;

$$\ce{Pt,Cl2}|\ce{Cl^-(aq)}||\ce{Ag^+(aq)}|\ce{Ag}$$

Obviouly, chlorine doesn't react in that direction, but gets oxidised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. You can remember the cell notation with the mnemonic "**r**eduction on the **r**ight."

So, on the right hand side, you should reduction process and on the left hand side you should show the oxidation process.

For example, for a Daniel cell, one can write

$$\ce{Zn|Zn^{2+}, SO_4^{2−}}||\ce{SO_4^{2−},Cu^{2+}}|\ce{Cu}$$

Now coming to your cell, $$\ce{Pt,Cl_2}|\ce{Cl^-(aq)}||\ce{Ag^+(aq)}|\ce{Ag}$$ is indeed written incorrectly because the writer seems to have the misconception that even in the cell notation, half cells must be written as a reduction.